# Why don't I see any Buzzer vehicles on the map anymore?

Tags: ps4, far-cry-4

I've completed 9 campaign missions, and was loving the Buzzer ultra-light helicopter that I found after the 7th mission.  I saved and quit for the night, and now that I've come back to continue playing, I don't see any Buzzer vehicles anywhere on the map.  What happened to them?  Do they only exist during certain times during the gameplay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are always Buzzers around. For example you can find them where the supply drop missions for the golden path are or near bell towers. I'd suggest, in case you already reside at your family's home (after doing the first mission for Yogi), buying a Buzzer (the sherpa outside your home sells you upgrades to your home, like a helipad).

Comment: Yeah, I died in a surprise attack by a clouded leopard and when I respawned the map showed Buzzers again.  Game glitch.  Next time it happens, I'm going to go to a place where I know they are always located to see if I can still use it even though the map doesn't show it.

Comment: @Alan as I already mentioned in my answer you'll can always have one in your homestead or for sure at cleared fortresses.

Answer (score 0):

Vehicles only display on the map when you are located close to them.
When you move out of their range, they become invisible on the map.

I have encountered many bugs but none like that.